# Using a ValueProvider with DatastoreIO.Read

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I am using dataflow with Java SDK, version 1.9.1 . 
I need to read a certain kind from the datastore, using DataStoreIO and create a PCollection< Entity >. I run the dataflow job using a TemplateRunner. The name of the kind I need to read will be passed in through PipelineOptions when the template is launched. (ie, it is not known at graph construction time)
How can I create a KindExpression using a ValueProvider for the kind name.

Eg. I could do this if the name is known at graph construction time-

```
KindExpression k = KindExpression.newBuilder().setName("abc").build()
PCollection<Entity> myentities = pipeline.apply(DatastoreIO.v1().read().withProjectId("my-project").withQuery(Query.newBuilder().addKind(k).build()));
```

How can I construct the query when i do not know the name in advance. For instance, TextIO has a provision to use "withoutValidation"

```
PCollection<String> mergeRuleTemplateString = pipeline
            .apply(TextIO.Read.from(options.getInputFile()).withoutValidation());
```

Is there something similar in DataStoreIO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but not in 1.9.1 - support for ValueProvider was added to DatastoreIO in 2.0.0 (JIRA [BEAM-1076](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-1076)). Note that it is currently only supported for literal GQL queries, via `.withLiteralGqlQuery(ValueProvider<String>)` ([javadoc](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.0.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/datastore/DatastoreV1.Read.html#withLiteralGqlQuery-org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ValueProvider-)).